# how to add a custom row to calculate total of a column for specific table in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, flexigrid, grocery-crud

i want to add a row which will show the total value of a column in **grocery crud**.I don't want it for every table just for few tables which has numerical values,so I don't wan't to modify the template indeed.Is it possible then how? and what if I change the template and how will I add a row that will calculate the total for few tables?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can *extend* **not** *modify* the codeigniter HTML table class to have a TFOOT element, then you add the totals to the footer. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916646/how-to-add-a-tfoot-row-to-table-generated-with-codeigniter-table-class) will show you how to extend the codeigniter html table class:

Comment: See my question care fully

Comment: think about tables semantically. a total of a column is either a header or footer element.  that is what you should use.  the CI frame work does not use a footer element, i showed you how to do that.  reading your question carefully is difficult with your writing skills.

Comment: He was asking a question about grocery CRUD, not CI